# Unable to install 'rstats-db/bigrquery' from ipython notebook

Tags: r, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook, tar

I'm trying to query Google Big Query from an R iPython notebook. I'm following this post here:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/04/google-cloud-platform-for-data-scientists-using-r-with-google-bigquery

It breaks when I run this line:

```
devtools::install_github("rstats-db/bigrquery", force = TRUE)
```

The full error message isn't very clear to me, I'll paste it below. But when I run it from an interactive R environment I get this:

```
sh: /usr/bin/gnutar: No such file or directory
sh: /usr/bin/gnutar: No such file or directory
Installation failed: error in running command
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/readr_1.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 233793 bytes (228 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 228 KB
```

It seems to be unable to unpack the files.

I've tried installing gnutar with brew, but it the error still occurs.

How can I get passed this error?

Full Error message:

```
Installing package into ‘/Users/user/Library/R/3.3/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Downloading GitHub repo rstats-db/bigrquery@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/rstats-db/bigrquery/zipball/master
Installing bigrquery
Warning message in utils::untar(src, exdir = target, compressed = "gzip"):
“‘/usr/bin/gnutar -xf '/var/folders/bx/t0zshghn4d97zrt6qfplsx0ngq83z6/T//RtmpvuCFsS/assertthat_0.2.0.tar.gz' -C '/var/folders/bx/t0zshghn4d97zrt6qfplsx0ngq83z6/T//RtmpvuCFsS/devtoolsb8f71357947'’ returned error code 127”Installation failed: error in running command
Warning message in utils::untar(src, exdir = target, compressed = "gzip"):
“‘/usr/bin/gnutar -xf '/var/folders/bx/t0zshghn4d97zrt6qfplsx0ngq83z6/T//RtmpvuCFsS/DBI_0.7.tar.gz' -C '/var/folders/bx/t0zshghn4d97zrt6qfplsx0ngq83z6/T//RtmpvuCFsS/devtoolsb8f4d592385'’ returned error code 127”Installation failed: error in running command
Warning message in utils::untar(src, exdir = target, compressed = "gzip"):
“‘/usr/bin/gnutar -xf '/var/folders/bx/t0zshghn4d97zrt6qfplsx0ngq83z6/T//RtmpvuCFsS/jsonlite_1.5.tar.gz' -C '/var/folders/bx/t0zshghn4d97zrt6qfplsx0ngq83z6/T//RtmpvuCFsS/devtoolsb8f40b600f1'’ returned error code 127”Installation failed: error in running command
Warning message in utils::untar(src, exdir = target, compressed = "gzip"):
“‘/usr/bin/gnutar -xf '/var/folders/bx/t0zshghn4d97zrt6qfplsx0ngq83z6/T//RtmpvuCFsS/readr_1.1.1.tar.gz' -C '/var/folders/bx/t0zshghn4d97zrt6qfplsx0ngq83z6/T//RtmpvuCFsS/devtoolsb8f2bae1fe6'’ returned error code 127”Installation failed: error in running command
'/Applications/anaconda/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  '/private/var/folders/bx/t0zshghn4d97zrt6qfplsx0ngq83z6/T/RtmpvuCFsS/devtoolsb8f2945f879/rstats-db-bigrquery-ad77f0e'  \
  --library='/Users/nickk/Library/R/3.3/library' --install-tests 

Reloading installed bigrquery
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your traceback it's hard to tell what happened. But you could try using the official release instead of the development one.

Try using this command instead:

```
install.packages("bigrquery")
```

As you can see in the [official release](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigrquery/index.html), support for `useLegacySQL` has already been [implemented](https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery/blob/master/R/query.r#L35).

Comment: Oh I see - I seem to be good at mis-diagnosing things. Can you tell me whether it's possible to use standard SQL? I don't seem to be able to get standardSQL queries to work.

Comment: It should be exactly as it is in the post you are following, something like: `todo_copies <- query_exec(sql, project = project, useLegacySql = FALSE)`. Did you try using `useLegacySql=False`? It didn't work?

Comment: No it's not. I've posted this question since you indicate it should be working:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45331678/unable-to-use-bigrquery-with-standard-sql