# Unable to use bigrquery with standard sql

Tags: r, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I'm working in an R ipython notebook (relative R newbie) and trying to extract data from Google Big Query using 'bigrquery'. I'm told this should be simple, but extracting using standard sql isn't working.

Here's my code:

```
require("bigrquery")

# Use your project ID here
project <- "project-id" # put your project ID here

standard_sql <- "SELECT year, month, day, weight_pounds FROM `publicdata.samples.natality` LIMIT 5"

legacy_sql <- "SELECT year, month, day, weight_pounds FROM [publicdata:samples.natality] LIMIT 5"

# doesn't work
standard_data <- query_exec(standard_sql, project = project, useLegacySql = FALSE)

# works
legacy_data <- query_exec(legacy_sql, project = project, useLegacySql = TRUE)
```

For the standard sql above it returns the following error:

```
Error: Invalid table name: `publicdata:samples.natality`
Traceback:

1. query_exec(standard_sql, project = project, useLegacySql = FALSE)
2. run_query_job(query = query, project = project, destination_table = destination_table, 
 .     default_dataset = default_dataset, create_disposition = create_disposition, 
 .     write_disposition = write_disposition, use_legacy_sql = use_legacy_sql, 
 .     quiet = quiet, ...)
3. wait_for(job, quiet = quiet)
4. stop(err$message, call. = FALSE)
```

It's suggesting that I've not entered the table name correctly for standard SQL, but I seemingly have and the query runs fine from the GBQ console.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Just in case - try false in all small chars

Comment: What version of bigrquery is installed for you? Could you print the result of `packageVersion("bigrquery")` for us?

Comment: small chars false didn't work - version is ‘0.4.1’ - is that the old one by any chance?

Comment: Also tried with table that I own and is entirely new.

Comment: Just as a note goose, when you reply to some comment for somebody remember to add their names such as "@Willian Fuks" so that we receive a notification in our Inbox. Neither me nor Mikhail received the notification of your last comment.

Comment: Thanks @WillianFuks - very helpful reminder.

Comment: Now I received the notification ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You sent the wrong variable to the function.

It should be `use_legacy_sql = FALSE` instead of `useLegacySql`. They [changed](https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery/commit/8d2bbd91ef740151b09fe489a0c347486fe7fb58) the variable name right after committing the new code.

Comment: It had to be something like that. Thanks so much for all your help!